# Embeding script using div not responsive / full screen

Tags: html, iframe, embed

Beginner here, so this is a pretty basic question.

I have a virtual photobooth running here: https://verve.vbooth.me/booth/kL0e1N6Y and the app runs full screen as needed.

The embed code provided is:

```html
<div id="vb-kL0e1N6Y"  style="height: 600px"></div>
<script src="https://app.virtualbooth.me/embed/kL0e1N6Y"></script>
<script>PhotoBooth.initWidget("vb-kL0e1N6Y", "kL0e1N6Y");</script>
```

When I run that with height of 100%, it does not maximise:
https://virtualbooth.ie/demo1/

Using the very basic code:

```html
<html>  
    <head> 
        <title>Test Photobooth</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="vb-kL0e1N6Y"  style="height: 100%"></div>
        <script src="https://app.virtualbooth.me/embed/kL0e1N6Y"></script>
        <script>PhotoBooth.initWidget("vb-kL0e1N6Y", "kL0e1N6Y");</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? Or is it a limit of the script that is forcing a smaller viewport?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the default style of browsers.
You can fix the problem with the style:

> *{margin:0; padding:0}

or

> body {margin:0; padding:0}

Also, You can use 'CSS reset' and 'CSS normalize'

Comment: Thanks, that worked to get rid of the boarder.  But the script / widget still does not appear full screen when embedded as it does when running on its own direct link. 

Viewing the source on script orginal page, has:

 body{
  max-width: 430px;

Is that causing my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Adding the following code solved my problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```